# How to resize images to certain size in Python PIL without distortion?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to crop images to 1000, 1000 using PIL in Python.

However, it always stretches the image to match the dimensions rather than cropping. Current code below.

Preferably, I would like to crop the original images evenly on the right and left while extending or reducing the height to 1000.

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('image.jpg')
new_img = img.resize((1000,1000))
new_img.save("image.jpg", "JPEG", optimize=True)
new_img.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `image.crop` method to crop the sides, followed by a `image.resize` to extend or reduce the height to 1000:

```
(width, height) = img.size
left = int((width - 1000)/2)
right = left + 1000
new_img = img.crop((left, 0, right, height))
new_img = new_img.resize((1000,1000))
```

Comment: I'm getting an error on this...

TypeError: Image.crop() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 5 were given

Comment: Apologies, the values need to be in a tuple. Answer has been adjusted.

Comment: @Jody Can you accept the answer if it solves the issue, or provide additional details if not?

Comment: it works if both the height and width are over 1000. If the height isn't, it will add black bars to each side. If the width isn't, it will distort. Works for my purposes as I can resize the image before. Marked as solved - thanks!

Answer (score -1):

In the python you can use the resize image with PILL library in this you want to import the PILL module

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("images/cat.jpg")
im.show()
resized_im = im.resize((round(im.size[0]*0.5), round(im.size[1]*0.5)))
resized_im.show()
resized_im.save('resizedBeach1.jpg')
```

Comment: You are basically reposting OPs code that doesn't work for him.

Comment: you had keep also that only. Then keep question in correct way.